# How to make fixed width for item separator in a FlatList with flexbox?

Tags: ios, react-native, grid, react-native-flexbox

I want to make a grid of elements with a separator with fixed width of 1 "*pixel*". Like in a `Photo` app grid for iOS.

For item width in a FlatList I use `flex` style, because I can not predict their width on different screens.

Code example: https://snack.expo.io/ryK_zPmEM

But on my `iPhone 7 Plus` (real device) i have got this result:
[image: iPhone 7 Plus screenshot]

The separator between the second and the third cell has a style `marginLeft: 1` but looks wider than the other two separators.

And this is a screenshot of the simulator for `iPhone 5S`:
[image: iPhone 5S Simulator screenshot]

The result is the **opposite**. You can also notice that the thickness of the separator between the **rows** is also different.

**The question is**: what value should be set for `margin` style so that separator looked the same for all screen sizes and did not change its width between the cells int the row?

*Or perhaps I need to calculate the exact value for the width of the cell instead of using* `flex: 1`?

Full code example:

```
const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
const ITEMS_PER_ROW = 4
const MARGIN_WIDTH = 1

const TOTAL_MARGIN_WIDTH = MARGIN_WIDTH * (ITEMS_PER_ROW - 1)
const CELL_SIZE = (WINDOW_WIDTH - TOTAL_MARGIN_WIDTH) / ITEMS_PER_ROW

const listData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

export default class App extends Component {
  _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.cell, (index % 4 !== 0) ? styles.cellMargin : {}]}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          columnWrapperStyle={styles.listColumn}

          data={listData}
          numColumns={ITEMS_PER_ROW}
          keyExtractor={i => i}
          renderItem={item => this._renderItem(item)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  list: {
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
    flex: 1,
  },
  listColumn: {
    marginTop: 1,
    height: CELL_SIZE,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  cell: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    flex: 1,
  },
  cellMargin: {
    marginLeft: MARGIN_WIDTH,
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Stmol please check with a real device.

Comment: @SathishSundharam look at my first screenshot, its taken from a real iPhone 7 Plus